# Capistrano deploy hangs at check_changes step

Tags: wordpress, capistrano

It hangs on the `check_changes` step at this command:

```
Command: cd /home/myproject/repo && git diff --name-only HEAD
```

With this output in terminal:

```
DEBUG [c3f0a05b]        content/plugins/akismet/views/notice.php[m
DEBUG [c3f0a05b]        :[K
```

A couple notes which may make this case unusual:

- This is deploying a WordPress site.
- WordPress core and plugins were (mistakenly) updated on the server using `wp-cli` so that production code and repository would be unsynced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution turned out to be simple. But it required a lot of useless googling before I finally figured it out by trial-and-error. Posting this as a reference for others who may find themselves in this situation.

The fix was to ssh into the server and remove the `repo` directory from the project root:

```
cd /home/myproject
mv -v repo /tmp/cap-repo
```

After this, I was able to run the `cap deploy` command successfully.

I would be interested in hearing an explanation for the `[m` and `:[K` output.